# In MS Access 2008, how do I search for asterisks (*)

Tags: microsoft-access, find-and-replace

As * is a wildcard character that matches any string, it gives me the first row, not the first row containing an asterisks.

Comment: Does `"[*]"` work?

Comment: No, unfortunately not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enclosing the asterisk in your search string in square brackets, i.e. "[*]", is in fact the correct answer.  This is according to [Microsoft documentation](http://bit.ly/yFLWou).  And here's the proof:

[image]

Works like a charm!  Perhaps what you are missing is the "Any Part of Field" setting?

Comment: Thanks, but not working, heres the proof: http://imgur.com/ysAC0. Im using Access 2007 SP2. H

Comment: Hey, Muleskinner!  YES, it DOES work - when you set the "Match" to "Any Part of Field" like I said specifically in my answer.  Setting Match to "Whole Field" as you show in your screen grab will only find a record where there is an asterisk AND NOTHING ELSE in the field.  Please accept my answer as correct since the real issue is the "Match" setting which I pointed out.  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, in my screenshot I made a mistake with the match settings. But I did try your suggestion and have to say that you are wrong - it might work for you and others, but it does not work for me, see http://imgur.com/Llyqz. I would really like to accept your answer, but how can I if it does not answer my question?

Comment: I hear you that it does not work for you - but that doesn't make me "wrong".  You said "it might work for you and others".  I'm saying as nicely as I can that it DOES work for me and I'm sure for most/many/all others.  Here's the video on YouTube: http://youtu.be/a-NHMQcz-bo   So the question is not "How do I..." (which I answered correctly!) but "Why doesn't this work for me?"  Good luck finding the answer...

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution. Find and Replace will remove an asterisk in Access VER 14 in 2016 MS Office.
Just use [*]  in the find and nothing in the replace. Access takes anything in the brackets literally so it finds the character and doesn’t treat it like a wildcard. Also don’t put quotes around [*]

Comment: It didn’t show the answer properly when I posted. In FIND just type an open bracket then the asterisk symbol then a closed bracket